# Emacs 24 and linux distributions

Tags: package-management, emacs, distribution-choice

I just downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and was very disappointed that emacs 24 was not yet supported for it. I found some links where you could build it from source, but regardless I am looking for a Linux distribution that has terrific support for emacs.

1. What Linux distribution would you recommend for emacs?
2. Which Linux distribution will be good with package managers?

I want package management to support a wide variety of packages and to be minimally time consuming. (For example MacPorts for OS X has treated me well so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to install a different distribution for that, you can just add Damien Cassou's [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cassou/emacs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge emacs-snapshot-common emacs-snapshot-bin-common emacs-snapshot emacs-snapshot-el emacs-snapshot-gtk emacs23 emacs23-bin-common emacs23-common emacs23-el emacs23-nox emacs23-lucid auctex emacs24 emacs24-bin-common emacs24-common emacs24-common-non-dfsg
sudo apt-get install emacs24 emacs24-el emacs24-common-non-dfsg
```